# marshmallow validate object without serializing

Tags: python, marshmallow

**Problem:** I have an object with some values and a schema which defines field and schema level validation for such an object using [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).
The schema can validate serialized data, which, for most used cases, is enough. But when I want to partially update the object, I have to serialize the already existing object, update the returned dictionary with the new fields, validate the dict and then reassign those values to the object. This is required to run the schema level validation.

**Question:** I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to validate partial updates. For example, partially loading the data, assigning it to the existing object and validating the object using the schema (not possible, because the validation function of a schema only accepts dicts)

> Note: I can not just recreate the object, because it is synced with the database. I have to assign the new values.

**Example:**

```
class Obj:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 2
  
  def update(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

class ObjSchema(Schema):
  a = fields.Integer()
  b = fields.Integer()

  @validates_schema
  def validate_whole_schema(self, data, **kwargs):
    ...


o = Obj()
sc = ObjSchema()
new_values = {
  "a": 3
}

# ugly partial update
o_data = sc.dump(o)
o_data.update(new_values)
errors = sc.validate(o_data)
if errors:
  ...
else:
  o.update(o_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have already solved this problem, but Marshmallow schema.load() offers a "partial" flag that will ignore missing fields when loading the schema.

Refer to the resource below:
https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#partial-loading